# Javascript load each file in folder

Tags: javascript

In my project I have got a folder with .csv files. I dont know how much - it could be 1, 0 or even 50. How can I load all of them with javascript or with some javascript plugin?

Comment: If you have a server process, you can request them using that. If not and they have a pattern like file1.csv, file2.csv, you can load them until you get an error. - Please provide more details about your setup, do you want to use jQuery? What. Have a look at the [help]

Comment: What is the context of your question? Is it JavaScript executed in a web browser, NodeJS server?

Answer (score 0):

Best way of doing so would be to use the `fs` module of NodeJS. You can read a file by using `fs.readFile()` and write to a file by using `fs.writeFile()`.